# How to add Kotlin support for normal Java Lib in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

When we want to use Kotlin in Android Studio, it's quite simple. Add the kotlin dependent library, and also add the Kotlin-Android plugin as below

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

However, if I have a normal library (Used to be Java), and want to write in Kotlin, should I add any plugin? The below definitely not working.

```
 apply plugin: 'java-library'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

There is no 'kotlin-library' that I find to add in. What should I add to my module gradle to have it able to compile Kotlin?

Comment: I suppose if you try to add a Kotlin file, the IDE will prompt you to configure Kotlin and clicking on OK might do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to add the *Kotlin* plugin:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin"
```

The `java-library` plugin was only recently added to *Gradle* and extends the `java` plugin. The naming does not expand to `kotlin` though.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks!. By the way, if I remove `apply plugin: 'java-library'`, I could still have Java code within it. So `Kotlin` plugin already includes support for Java, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it's worth testing.

Answer (score 2):

As it been said you need to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
```

but you also need to add at least

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

to your dependency section of kotlin library module, otherwise standard library kotlin features would not work. E.g. you won't have `@JvmStatic` annotation, and so on.

The sample `build.gradle` of `kotlin` library module can look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

`$kotlin_version` should be defined in project `build.gradle` file.

The sample is taken from library project in Idea and tested to work with Android Studio project (tested with `Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2`) as a library dependency to an `app` module.

Comment: This is a different answer from the question. I have way to use Kotlin in my app, and aware of all the library setting. My question is on having Kotlin as a separate module library (used to be java-library).

Comment: Indeed this is the answer to your question. You create a java library module in android studio (lets say its name is `lib`), add `apply plugin: 'kotlin'` to this file (you can remove `apply plugin: 'java-library'`) and add `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"` to the dependency section. In your app module you should add this dependecy: `compile project(':lib')`.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more straightforward and your question is really useful, as I also faced similar problem about a year ago. The reason I mentioned dependency section not because you don't know about it, but because someone else who will read the answers, might not know about it. When you create java library module, it won't have anything about kotlin by default and simply adding kotlin plugin may not be enough.

Comment: Made exactly like in your answer but when try to build the project getting a lot of such errors: "Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.String'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library"

Answer (score -2):

You need to add in your project app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

And add in your project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```